# How to get current authenticated user id using Vuejs and Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, authentication, vue.js

I am using Vuejs as my frontend and I would simply like to get the current logged in user's id from Laravel and display it. How would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by many way to get  auth user id [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart)

```
Auth::user()->id;

Auth::id();
```

by vue js

```
$http.get('api/user').then(response => {
   console.log(response.body);
})
```

Comment: If you want to pass it to a VueJS element you can use a prop. e.g.
`<custom :user-id={{Auth::id()}}></custom>`

Comment: You're assuming he has vue ressource tho

Answer (score 39):

Other option is to do it the same way as the `crsf` token.

```
// header.blade.php
<meta name="user-id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">

// main.js
Vue.prototype.$userId = document.querySelector("meta[name='user-id']").getAttribute('content');

// component

mounted() {
    console.log(this.$userId)
}
```

Comment: Well I find this answer very suitable for me. Thanks but better do it like this 

`@if(Auth::check()) <meta name="user-id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"> @endif`

Comment: If the user isn't always logged in, you can also use optional like `<meta name="user-id" content="{{ optional(Auth::user())->id }}">`

Comment: How can I populate `this.$userId` to a textfield?

Answer (score 3):

```
If you are using authentication created by the 
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth

You can add to

// app.blade.php or whatever you have maybe master.blade.php
 @if (Auth::check()) 
         <meta name="user_id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" />
 @endif 

Then in the app.js add
Vue.prototype.$userId = document.querySelector("meta[name='user_id']").getAttribute('content');


Now if you want to get the logged in  user id and pass it to a hidden input field the first declare it as 

<script>

export default {
        props: ['app'],
        data()
        {
            return{
                user_id: this.$userId,
            }
        },

    }
</script>

  // Finally in your MyVueComponent.vue
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" v-model="user_id">
```

To  test try making the type="text" instead of "hidden" and you see that it is shows you the current id

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to pass data to my Header component, so I thought I may share the way I'm doing it

```
<fronend-header :current-user="{{ json_encode(['isLoggedIn'=>auth()->check() ? true : false, 'user'=>auth()->check() ? auth()->user() : null]) }}" />
```

On the vuejs side

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "frontend-header",

        props: {
            currentUser: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

didn't tried it on logged in state yet, but I'll do any needed changes if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case in Laravel 9 I don't have Vue object inside app.js as it's initiated via createInertiaApp.
So I have found a way to do this by modifying only app.blade.php and my Page.vue file.

Simply:

app.blade.php:

```
window.user_id: {!! auth()->check()?auth()->user()->id:'null' !!}
```

Page.vue (the very top):

```
<script setup>
...
const user_id = window.user_id;
...
```

And then inside my Page.vue I can use {{ user_id }} anywhere inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried the above solutions but I'm getting an error because there's no logged in user yet. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null`
I added @else then is worked.
`@if (Auth::check()) <meta name="user_id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" />@else <meta name="user_id" content="0" /> @endif` hope will help someone