# How to display edit/delete buttons to the user that made that post?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm developing a simple forum with Laravel and VueJS. On the thread viewwhere all the posts that belong to that threads are displayed I want to show an edit and a delete button ONLY to those posts that the logged in user made. So, the user can edit and delete his own posts, but not others. I've searched on both Laravel and VueJS documentations, as well as Laracasts forum and here... but nothing works for me (not sure what I'm doing wrong).

I'm using Laravel's blade templates and Vue components all together. This is my code:

**thread.blade.php:**

```
@section('content')
<div class="header">
    <h1>this is a thread</h1>
    <forum-search ></forum-search>
</div>
<div class="container-block">
    <thread :userId="{{ auth()->id() }}"></thread>
</div>
@endsection
```

**thread.vue:**

```
<template>
<!-- display this block of code ONLY when the user is logged in -->
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px" v-if="userId == post.user_id">
    <!-- edit/delete buttons -->
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'thread',
    components: { quillEditor },
    props: ['userId'],
    data(){}
</script>
```

I tried few combinations `<thread userId="{{ auth()->id }}"></thread>`, `<thread userId="{{ auth()->id() }}"></thread>`, `<thread userId="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></thread>` or `<thread userId="{{ Auth::id() }}"></thread>` as people in the posts below suggested... but still not working as I expected. Any idea?

Laracasts: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/i-want-to-show-delete-button-only-to-its-post-owner-in-vuejs
StackOverflow: [How to get current authenticated user id using Vuejs and Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703364/how-to-get-current-authenticated-user-id-using-vuejs-and-laravel)

Comment: using `<thread :userId="{{ auth()->id() }}"></thread>` what do you get ?

Comment: Where is `post.user_id` set?

Comment: `post.user_id` comes from the json I get from my api resource through `axios.get('/api/threads/' + thread_id)`

Comment: @N69S - it says 'userId is not defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to do things like this I generally use policies as explained here : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies

After the policy for the ressource is set you have to use it as shown in the doc :
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-blade-templates

so in your blade you'll have

```
@can('edit', $resource)
    <thread></thread>
@endcan
```

instead of

```
<thread :userId="{{ auth()->id() }}"></thread>
```

The prop will no longer be needed

Comment: Seems weird to me... Did you show us all of the code in your component or not ?
Cause the way I wrote it means only thread owner will see it... It's not the way it meant to work IMO

Comment: I just showed the code that I thought would be relevant; between the template tags, I do have a `v-for loop (post, index) in thread.posts` to display all the posts in a thread

Comment: Sorry for the time between your answer and mine, I was busy on saturday.
Had that correct your problem ?

Comment: It worked but not exactly as I wanted... I may haven't explained what I was trying to do well enough.
I found an alternative answer in another post. What finally worked for me was: `<thread :auth_user='@json($auth_user)'></thread>` on my `thread.blade.php` template, and a `v-if="auth_user.id === post.user.id"` inside the thread.vue buttons that I wanted to show ONLY to own user's posts. THANK YOU VERY MUCH for yor help though!